# Using a checkbox within an checkbox accordion?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, accordion

I am trying to create a filter for a website, I made an accordion using check boxs, and I would like to put check boxes within it using

```
<input name="name" value="value" type="checkbox"/>
```

However the check box itself wont show.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="container">
    <section id="accordion">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" />
            <label for="check-1">Continent</label>                  
                <form action="">
                    Europe<input name="animal" value="Cat" type="checkbox"/> 
                </form>                 
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check-2" />
            <label for="check-2">Country</label>
                <form action="">
                    UK<input name="animal" value="Cat" type="checkbox"/> 
                </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check-3" />
            <label for="check-3">League / Competition</label>
            <form action="">
                        Premier League<input name="animal" value="Cat" type="checkbox"/> 
                </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check-4" />
            <label for="check-4">Date</label>
            <form action="">
                        march 13th<input name="animal" value="Cat" type="checkbox"/> 
                </form>
        </div>


    </section>
```

and the CSS:

```
* {
    font-family: Arial, sans;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1, h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    text-align:left;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

#container {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 20%;
}
#accordion input {
    display: none;
}

#accordion label {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: .25em;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .125em;
    padding: .25em 1em;
    z-index: 20;
}

#accordion label:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}

#accordion input:checked + label {
    background: #ccc;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    color: white;
    margin-: 0;
}

#accordion form{
    background: #f7f7f7;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:10;
}

#accordion from input{
    padding: 1em;
}

#accordion input:form {
}

#accordion input:checked ~ form {
    border-bottom-left-radius: .25em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .25em;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: .125em;
}
```

DEMO here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPdzWK

Comment: Maybe you should remove `#accordion input {
    display: none;
}` Or change it to `#accordion > div > input { display: none }` if you want to hide the checkbox higher up in the dom but not the one in the form.

Comment: fixed the problem based on your answer, instead of removing or changing this, i added: 

    `#accordion div form input{
         display:inline;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

So you have a line `#accordion input { display: none }`, this will hide all the `input`s you have.

If you only want to display the `input` in the `form` and hide the other ones you can do: `#accordion > div > input { display: none }` which selects the `input` that is a direct child of `div` which itself is a direct child of `#accordion`.